# Is there a way to shuffle random element from a list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a number from a list randomly as soon as I open the page without needing to click the number to change. Tried checking online, but had no luck finding any working solutions.

Update 1: It doesn't necessarily have to be a number. Also, below is my code so far. Only when I click the text changes. I'm still not able to have it dynamically show different "randomQuote" every time I open the page in the app

Update 2: Figured it out :)

```
  static List randomQuote = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','f'];

  Random random = new Random();
  var shuffleList = randomQuote.toList()..shuffle();
  int index = 0;

  void changeIndex() {

    setState(() => index = Random().nextInt(shuffleList.length));

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, top: 5, left: 20, right: 20),
            child: Text(
              shuffleList[index].toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto-boldItalics',
                fontSize: 17,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in the `initState` function:

```
var myList= [1,2,3,4,5];
myList.shuffle();

// Display `myList.first`
```

Comment: I tried adding shuffle to my list but I kept getting error. Can you please check my code. I updated my original post above

Comment: Thanks for your help. Posted the working code in my original post.

Comment: no problem @Advik! 

btw you used both `shuffle` and `random` function in your solution, i hope that will not be too random :) you could just use either one, but not a big issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your randomized function in your init state

i.e.

```
void initState(){ int randomNumber=Random().nextInt(yourList.length) }
```

then you can use randomNumber whatever you want.

Comment: I'm still having trouble getting my list to dynamically change. Can you please check my my original post above. I updated it with what I have so far. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Posted the working code in my original post.

Answer (score -1):

You can try shuffle(), which is provide with the Lists in flutter.
example :

```
listObjects.shuffle();
```